# Pause image loading in coil onscroll in lazycolumn in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

Pause image loading in  coil  onscroll  in lazycolumn in jetpack compose android

We are using Coil to load images with jetpack compose , earlier in glide with recylerview or other lists we had the option to pause loading images when we scrolled , it was an efficient way to prevent lag on scroll , Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As per the guide, in Coil 2.x they have already managed this. According to this [section](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/upgrading/#disk-cache) of the guide

[image: screenshot]

Infact, this was one of the [issue](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/933) in coil 2.0 where it didn't cancelled the request when the scoped was cancelled. This issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the item is visible you can load the image otherwise don't load it.

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()
val fullyVisibleIndices: List<Int> by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        val layoutInfo = state.layoutInfo
        val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
        if (visibleItemsInfo.isEmpty()) {
            emptyList()
        } else {
            val fullyVisibleItemsInfo = visibleItemsInfo.toMutableList()

            val lastItem = fullyVisibleItemsInfo.last()

            val viewportHeight = layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset

            if (lastItem.offset + lastItem.size > viewportHeight) {
                fullyVisibleItemsInfo.removeLast()
            }

            val firstItemIfLeft = fullyVisibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull()
            if (firstItemIfLeft != null && firstItemIfLeft.offset < layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset) {
                fullyVisibleItemsInfo.removeFirst()
            }

            fullyVisibleItemsInfo.map { it.index }
        }
    }
}
LazyColumn(
    state = state,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(30.dp)
) {
    items(100) { index -> 
        val isVisible by remember(index) {
            derivedStateOf {
                fullyVisibleIndices.contains(index)
            }
        }
        Text(
            index.toString(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(if (isVisible) Color.Green else Color.Transparent)
                .padding(30.dp)
        )
    }
}
```